# Rust draw and update in window

Tags: rust, graphics, gtk, cairo

I'm very new to Rust and rarely do any kind of graphics or UI stuff, so expect dumb mistakes.

I am trying to create a program that runs a simulation and displays its changing state over time. For this I want to create a window and then draw stuff on it, and have the stuff that's drawn change. Ideally it would be great if it were optimized for placing individual pixels (with the expectation that most of the time only a few pixels will change per timestep), but for now I'll settle for anything where I can run some code, display the result, run some more code, and refresh the display.

What I have so far:

```
fn main() {
let app = Application::builder()
    .application_id("org.example.HelloWorld")
    .build();

app.connect_activate(|app| {
    let win = ApplicationWindow::builder()
        .application(app)
        .default_width(320)
        .default_height(200)
        .title("Hello, World!")
        .build();

    let draw_area = DrawingArea::new();
    win.add(&draw_area);
    draw_area.connect_draw(|_unused, f| {
        f.set_source_rgb(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        f.paint();
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
        f.set_source_rgb(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
        f.paint();
        Inhibit(false)
    });
    win.show_all();
});
app.run();
}
```

I would like this to show an all-red window, wait for a second, and then show an all-green one. Instead it waits for a second and shows an all-green window. How can I restructure it so that I can update the display at intervals I control?

Comment: I wrote a chess app in Python using the `DrawingArea`, and I figured out I could force the `DrawingArea` to draw if I called its `hide()` and `show()` methods in sequence (in that order). It's a bit of a hacky solution, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know GTK, but most GUI systems have some fairly common properties here so I'll give you a generic answer since no one else has yet:

You need to *return control to the event loop* any time you want “time to pass” properly. That is, never use `thread::sleep`; if you want to do something later, use the event loop's timer mechanism that will call a callback later. (I couldn't find where the `gtk` crate has one of those, but I'm almost certain it will.)

Also, you need to consider that your `draw` callback will, probably, be called *whenever the window is resized* for the purpose of completely redrawing. It is rare for a GUI to offer a “retained” widget that remembers what pixels it should display across resize events; usually, you need your own image buffer to do that if you want it, and for most animation purposes, the conventional thing to do is to redraw everything whenever you want it to change. If you have an application that is slowly placing specific pixels, you should *probably* keep your own image buffer.

Comment: I got a little farther messing around. I changed `draw` to reference state, which I think is necessary, and the window will change as that state changes over time - but the window only updates when I mess with it by resizing, as you said. I'm trying to trigger that behavior from code.

One thing I'm struggling with is rust-specific multithreading. It seems like the window doesn't display until ` app.run();` is called, but that call doesn't return, and I don't know how to refer to `win` or `draw_area` from other threads. Unrelated, do you know a system that would let me keep the image buffer?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask a drawing area to (re)draw itself by calling [`queue_draw`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk/prelude/trait.WidgetExt.html#tymethod.queue_draw) (Source : [here](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk/struct.DrawingArea.html))

> Draw signals are normally delivered when a drawing area first comes
> onscreen, or when it’s covered by another window and then uncovered.
> You can also force an expose event by adding to the “damage region” of
> the drawing area’s window; `WidgetExt::queue_draw_area()` and
> `Window::invalidate_rect()` are equally good ways to do this. You’ll
> then get a draw signal for the invalid region.

Knowing this, you could bind a call to `queue_draw` to a timer, which would tick every *p*, where *p* would be a time period of your choice. I did it in the past and it works fine. In C, I used [`Glib::SignalTimeout::connect`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1SignalTimeout.html) (I don't know what the equivalent is in `gtk-rs`).

So, in conclusion, every *p* milliseconds, `queue_draw` would be called on your drawing area which would trigger its draw function (the callable parameter you passed to `connect_draw`) and redraw it. If you do this, remove this line:

```rust
thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(1000));
```

which only blocks the main loop.

Comment: This sounds like the C version of what I'm trying to do. I made some progress by making the draw method reference mutable state, but I've only figured out how to trigger it on certain actions (button clicks, basically.)

Comment: I think [this](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/latest/docs/glib/source/fn.timeout_add.html) is the equivalent in Rust. I am really not familiar with Rust however..

Comment: Can you talk a little more about how that would be plugged in? I'm not clear how it relates to the other components

Comment: @EdwardPeters I added some details in my answer.

Comment: Okay, I think I see how we'd want that to work, but when I try it rust complains that I'm moving the reference to `win` between threads - the glib timer presumably creates new ones, and Rust doesn't like me sending the window object there.

Comment: Ok, I don't know about those possible limitations in Rust. In C/C++, this is how I solve this...